# Alinear Imagen a texto html en cabecera

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Necesito alinear una sección de cabecera en un código.

Tengo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y quiero obtener algo como esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El código es:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top: 20px;">
        <a href="{{ url('/') }}">
          <img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}" alt="" class="img-responsive" width="60" style="margin: 0 auto;" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    Entrar
                </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      </ul>

      <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <!-- Authentication Links -->

        <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Registrarse</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Inicio> <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="{{ url('/x') }}">x</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Podrían ayudarme?

Gracias

Comment: Hola Andres, bienvenido. Estas en stack Overflow en español asi que tienes que traducir la pregunta al español para que no sea cerrada. A menos que quisieras ponerla en la version inglesa, que entonces te recomiendo borrar esta y hacerla en http://stackoverflow.com . Un saludo

Comment: Una solución es hacer el .container (solamente del menú) flexible: `align-items: center; display: flex; justify-content: space-between`.

Answer (score 2):

No sé si es lo que buscas, pero es más o menos así lo que buscas?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row" style="background:#000; height:50px; margin-top: 100px;">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <a href="">link1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <center><img src="http://img.segundamano.mx/thumbs/63/6395391246.jpg" style="height:50px"/></center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <a href="" class="pull-right">otros links</a>
    <br>
    <a href="" class="pull-right">otros links</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He puesto col-xs porqué el sitio para el resultado visible en esta página es pequeño pero puedes poner dentro de la clase `class="col-xs-4 col-md-4"` todo junto para que sea igual para todas las pantallas.